# Откуда взялся еще один объект (почему вызывается два деструктора)?

Tags: c++, классы, объекты, конструктор, деструктор

Изучаю книгу по C++. Начал играться с одним примером косвенного обращения к объекту и увидел такую вещь: во время уничтожения объекта `Pointer2` был ожидаемо уничтожен и объект `Foo`, но при завершении программы какой-то другой объект `Foo` был снова уничтожен (вызван его деструктор).
Какой именно, я понять не могу.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  Foo() {std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;}
  Foo(const Foo & other)
  {
    std::cout << "Hello copy world!" << std::endl;
  }
  ~Foo() {std::cout << "Goodby world!" << std::endl;}
  void MemberOfFoo()
  {
    std::cout << "Hello from MemberOfFoo!" << std::endl;
  }

};    

class Pointer {
private:
  Foo* f;
public:
  Pointer(Foo* foo) : f(foo) {}
  ~Pointer()
  {
    delete f;
  }
  Foo* operator->() const { return f; }
};

class Pointer2 {
private:
  Pointer p;
public:
  Pointer2(Foo* foo) : p(foo) {}  
  Pointer operator->() const { return p; }
};    

int main()
{
  {
    Pointer2 p(new Foo);
    p->MemberOfFoo();
    std::cout << "Ok" << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
  return 0;

}
```

И, самое главное, программа падает при освобождении памяти из под Foo (delete f).

Comment: `p->MemberOfFoo();` возвращает _временную копию_ `Pointer p` которая сразу и уничтожается. Далее уничтожается `Pointer2 p` что и приводит к двойному удалению.`Pointer::f`

Comment: @MaximTimakov Спасибо.

Comment: Это называется rule of 4/5/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот оператор

```
Pointer operator->() const { return p; }
```

следует сделать такими двумя:

```
const Pointer& operator->() const { return p; }
Pointer& operator->() { return p; }
```